# Excel remove all empty rows 600 000 rows and reformat

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with 600 000 rows.

It looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4 Value1: 1
5 Value2: 2
6 Value3: 3
7
8
9
10 Value1: 1
11 Value2: 2
12 Value3: 3
13
14
15
...
599998: Value1: 1
599999: Value2: 2
600000: Value3: 3
```

My goal is to remove all the empty rows and place the values like this:

```
  A       B       C
1 Value1  Value2  Value3
2 ...
```

I've tried selecting all rows -> F5 special "empty values" but it always says "Selection too big" even with like a 1000 rows ...

Anyone who could help me out a tiny bit I would be forever thankful!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you can select just the column with data before select special > blanks, or just sort the column if that is an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change `SheetName` to the name of the sheet where your data is, in this line :

```
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
```

And this will put the desired output in a new sheet :

```
Sub testFrankLucas()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim DaTa() As Variant

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    LastRow = LastRow_1(wS)
    ReDim DaTa(1 To 3, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 6
        With wS
            DaTa(1, UBound(DaTa, 2)) = .Cells(i, 1).Offset(3, 0)
            DaTa(2, UBound(DaTa, 2)) = .Cells(i, 1).Offset(4, 0)
            DaTa(3, UBound(DaTa, 2)) = .Cells(i, 1).Offset(5, 0)
            ReDim Preserve DaTa(LBound(DaTa, 1) To UBound(DaTa, 1), LBound(DaTa, 2) To UBound(DaTa, 2) + 1)
        End With 'wS
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve DaTa(LBound(DaTa, 1) To UBound(DaTa, 1), LBound(DaTa, 2) To UBound(DaTa, 2) - 1)

    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    'wsNew.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(DaTa, 2), UBound(DaTa, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(DaTa)
    For i = LBound(DaTa, 2) To UBound(DaTa, 2)
        For j = LBound(DaTa, 1) To UBound(DaTa, 1)
            With wsNew
                .Cells(i, j).Value = DaTa(j, i)
            End With 'wsNew
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


Public Function LastRow_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
    With wS
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            LastRow_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            LastRow_1 = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Could you help me out maybe how to run a macro? I have never run one before.

Comment: Press Alt+F11 to open VBE. On the left side, right click and Insert a module. Paste the code in there. Click somewhere in `Sub testFrankLucas` and press F5! Et voilà! Go back to Excel and enjoy! ;)

Comment: Maybe important to know I am on a Mac is it possible?

Comment: I am not able to find the Developer tab or open the VBE :'(

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-run-edit-or-delete-a-macro-fc5fb55d-124d-4cc7-bae0-111c9c26e234#bmxl

Comment: Okay I managed to run the macro but I get this error: "Error 9 during runtime" And something with subscript is out of scope... the error message is in dutch I did my best translating :)

Comment: @FrankLucas : See this first : https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/visual_basic_editor2011.php

Comment: @FrankLucas : On which line did I got stuck? It should be highlighted in Yellow when you click on Debug

Comment: It highlighted this line:  "Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")"

Comment: @FrankLucas : My bad, I forgot to say that you have to change `SheetName` to the name of the sheet where your data is!^^

Comment: Okay that worked but I get an error 13 on this line now "    wsNew.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(DaTa, 2), UBound(DaTa, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(DaTa)
" something with datatypes do not match

Comment: @FrankLucas : try the new version of the code in the answer (I edited it)

Comment: Works like a charm! Only 1 thing I get only the Value1 & Value2 not the Value3. Column A is empty B is Value1 and C is Value2

Comment: @FrankLucas : Are you values really in row 4,5,6 then 10,11,12 and so on? If not, tune the rows `DaTa(1, UBound(DaTa, 2)) = .Cells(i, 1).Offset(3, 0)` and adjust the values in `Offset`, change 3,4,5 there to fit your need! ;)

Comment: Oh no value1 is in row 5 I did not realise this I will edit the macro

Comment: @FrankLucas : so instead of 3,4,5 use 4,5,6 ! ;)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much I will accpet your answer!